# Magento 2 : Install an Extension

Tags: magento2, extensions, marketplace

[image]Has anyone installed an extension that doesn't error out from the marketplace using the extension manager? If so what am I doing wrong? It seams pretty straight forward. click module click install backup and thin install. But errors every time.

Comment: What extension are you installing and what error are you getting?

Comment: I have tried several but the latest is the amazon pay and login app. I cant seem to find where it is erring out but i get a red box on the install page saying there is an error and to click the roleback button. and that button never works. it will not let me post the log here its too long.

Comment: You should be able to post the log. Just trim it down only to the relevant information.

Comment: [2018-04-24 12:54:03 UTC] Job "setup:maintenance:enable []" has started
Enabled maintenance mode

[2018-04-24 12:54:03 UTC] Job "setup:maintenance:enable []" has been successfully completed
[2018-04-24 12:54:03 UTC] Job "setup:cache:disable []" has started
[2018-04-24 12:54:03 UTC] Job "setup:cache:disable []" has been 
successfully completed
[2018-04-24 12:54:03 UTC] Update is already in progress.
[2018-04-24 12:55:03 UTC] Job "update {"components":[{"name":"amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-magento-2-module","version":"2.0.4"}]}" has been started

Comment: [2018-04-24 12:55:04 UTC] Starting composer update...
[2018-04-24 12:55:07 UTC] ./composer.json has been updated
[2018-04-24 12:56:02 UTC] Update is already in progress.
[2018-04-24 12:56:10 UTC] Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 2 installs, 23 updates, 1 removal
- Removing gecko-packages/gecko-php-unit (v2.2)
Removing Gecko-packages/GeckoPhpUnit
Package sjparkinson/static-review is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use phpro/grumphp instead.
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files

Comment: [2018-04-24 12:56:10 UTC] Composer update completed successfully
[2018-04-24 12:56:10 UTC] Job "update {"components":[{"name":"amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-magento-2-module","version":"2.0.4"}]}" has successfully completed
[2018-04-24 12:58:08 UTC] Job "setup:cache:enable ["config layout block_html collections reflection db_ddl eav customer_notification config_integration config_integration_api full_page translate config_webservice"]" has started

[2018-04-24 12:58:21 UTC] Job "setup:maintenance:disable []" has been successfully completed

Answer (score 0):

Log in to your SSH, navigate to root of you Magento installation and run following commnads:

`php bin/magento cache:clean`

and then:

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Comment: ran both "nothing to import" issue is still the same and it will not let me roll back from cli either.

Comment: do you have any theme installed?

Comment: nothing other than the stock instillation it is a fresh install